# Is there a way to list all excel files containing Macros in a Folder and Subfolders?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, windows-search, file-search

I would like to list all Excel Files containing Macros in a Folder and Subfolders.

Is it possible to do it with Windows Search or Agent Ransack or Filesearch Pro?

Comment: Macro-enabled excel files have `.xlsm` extension. Search for it.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio binary files can also have macros saved (.xlsb)

Comment: Search *.xlsm, *.xls directly。

Comment: @Lee `.xls` doesn't support macros.

Comment: @PeterH You are correct.

Comment: @spikey_richie `*.xls` files have always supported macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a limited number of `Macro-Enabled` workbook types, which are

- `.XLSM` (workbook)
- `.XLTM` (template file)
- `.XLSB` (binary file, nod to PeterH)

Searching your drive (using the tool of your choice) for these file extensions will list all Excel files which are **usually** used for macros.

If you attempt to save an Excel workbook that contains macros, but choose a format which doesn't support macros, you'll receive the following prompt

[image]

Comment: you can still save a file as .XLSM without actually having any macros in there

Comment: and binary files can contain macros (.xlsb)

Comment: "you can still save a file as .XLSM without actually having any macros in there" _ I thought that was pretty obvious, so I didn't mention it explicitly. `.xlsb` is a new one on me.

Comment: It is obvious, but not what OP asked for, and yh i always use binary files as default as they are often smaller in size than .xlsm

Comment: Adjustments made, thanks.

Comment: @spikey_richie You omitted `*.xls` files which have always supported macros (since macros were a thing).  But the OP asked for files that **contained** macros.  Your list includes files that **are able to contain** macros -- not those that actually contain a macro.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Feel free to add an alternative answer.

Comment: Since the OP accepted your answer, there's not much point. As is common, it may be that what he really wanted is not what he asked for.  In any event, I don't believe that his stated requirements can be satisfied in Windows Search, and I'm not familiar with Ransack.